# Android - integrate with Toodledo api - using Oauth demo app

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, authorization

My App should integratie with the Toodledo-API with toodledo. I use the demo app Oauth2.

What is the right URI to use?

```
 https://api.toodledo.com/3/account/authorize.php?response_type=code&client_id=mypersonalidddd&state= MTA&scope=basic%20tasks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Demo app seems not to work with the new authentication *oauth2*.

How to move forward for Android integration with Toodledo:

My suggested approach is:

1 = Study the Playground API well.
2 = Check the PHP example for details.

Finally I got it working. I am very new in this area, so I don't feel free to post my solution yet.

I do hope the real experts make a very simple Demo with oauth2, just like to one in PHP.